# Errors including gtkmm.h

Tags: c++, user-interface, include, gtkmm

I wanted to compile a C++ program which includes the gtkmm.h file to build a small application.

I took the code fromt the Gnome Developer site ([Link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en)). I am currently on ArchLinux with kernel 4.1.15 on a x64 Laptop using the i3 desktop.

## The Code:

### example.cc

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto app =
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
      "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

  Gtk::Window window;
  window.set_default_size(200, 200);

  return app->run(window);
}
```

### The Makefile:

```
program:
    g++ simple.cc -o simple `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

## The Errors:

There is so much output i think it is better to link to an [external site](http://pastebin.com/WMhg5K26) because it's really big. On the site you can only see the first 100lines of the Error. If you want erverything, please mail me. (it repeats itself, it just tells the same about different files, invalid functioncalls etc.).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What _external site_ are you talking about?

Comment: Did you bother reading the very first error, which tells you exactly what to do? `#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do what the compiler tells you: add `-std=c++11` to the command line.